# How to start a container in cri-o with only specifying the image name?

Tags: containers, cri-o

I am trying to achieve something like

```
docker run -it <image_name> bash
```

I want to specify the image to run and do not care about anything else.

`crictl` requires config files for both a container and a pod for the run command, if I am not mistaken.

```
[hbaba@ip-XX-XX-XXX misc]$ sudo crictl -r /run/crio/crio.sock run -h
....

USAGE:
   crictl run [command options] container-config.[json|yaml] pod-config.[json|yaml]
```

I am looking for the simplest way of starting a container, possibly with only a specified image.